# Sound muted in Firefox (MacBook Air OSX 10.8.5)

Tags: audio, firefox

I am quite new to using Macs - so apologies if this is super trivial.

When browsing Youtube / Vimeo all sounds are muted. I have checked that the sound is correctly set on the video player. This is working fine on Safari. I know it is possible to mute certain apps in Win7 - is there a similar functionality in OSX?

Thanks!

Comment: There is some more information here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Muting_browser

Comment: Hi - sorry this doesn't help, I am trying to un-mute and I don't have any of these add ons installed.